# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable (PROJECT ADDED!!)

Tags: android, google-maps, noclassdeffounderror

this is kinda a newbie question, but I'm having this problem even following the Google guides.

My app is crashing when seeing a map, with this throw:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

it had happened only with **Samsung Galaxy S III**, I'm trying to some other like Samsung Galaxy ACE, Samsung WIFI 5.0 and some others and **that doesn't happen**.

1.- I have added my project library.
[image]

2.- I have the jar on my build path:
[image]

[image]

3.- I have followed the Getting Started on Google Maps V2 for Android:

**part of AndroidManifest.xml**

```
      <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

   <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
   <permission android:name="my.package.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
   <uses-permission android:name="my.package.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

   <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

   <!-- Send the registration id to the server -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

          <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBCYlMBZVuvPtCQm9mznppJTCnBbH8QRFI"/>


        <activity ...
```

**My activity code (mappa.class) where it crashes**

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
     if (layout != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) layout.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(layout);
     }
     try {
    // HERE IT'S WHEN IT CRASHES!! THE FOLLOWING LINE
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmappa, container, false); 

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

**And my layout fragmentmappa.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` generally inidcates you have not referenced the library project properly. can you cross check again??. But the snap shot posted looks Ok

Comment: yeah, that's the problem... even in a lot of devices it's working

Comment: It seems everything is fine in your code, try clean and build and then uninstall and install the app. And see if it works.

Comment: I was assuming that when I export, it was cleaned by itself... I debugged in my device and it was OK, and I was debuging, but this error was when I exported it.... I can't still avoid to be a newbie :P :P.

@TheLittleNaruto if you want, post that as response and I will approve it ;)

Thanks

Comment: Sure! it'll be good for others too :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems everything is fine in your code, Do following:

1. clean and build and
2. then first uninstall and then install the app.

And see if it works.

Comment: I can't believe this solved this bug. No class bug from Samsung library was solved from this.

Comment: hihihihi xD What can I say! It's just matter of uncertainty ? @coolcool1994