# Run Time Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Tags: java, android, google-maps, service, intellij-idea

```
// MyActivity.class 

package com.example.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}

// main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

// AndoidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.maps"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

1. Compilation - no error
2. Runtime Error is there.
3. Added google services jar to lib as well as modules
4. using intellij idea
5. Took this code from google website
6. Also took reference from android developers

Below is my error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable 
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4247)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
at com.example.maps.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you try a clean and build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-in-android

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760834/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480116/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-project-adde

Comment: And finally, see also: https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+com.google.android.gms.R%24styleable (and a few more related links on the right here; there's a few different answers but I suspect at least one has a solution for you).

Comment: No it doesn't have! I have read the other stackoverflow questions as well!

Answer (score 0):

you just replace the map fragment with the following code like that

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Code replaced still I get Similar Error: 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

And the app says Unfortunately, maps has stopped working

Comment: you which ide you develope eclipse or any other

Comment: @Dhaval No need to change because his SDK version is 15 so it will be used MapFragment which is supported >12 API level.

Comment: @Piyush, Yes your are write

Comment: I got it back on its original state!

I read other stack overflow questions but didn't get my answer from it